# How to send email using nodemailer with hostinger professional email?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send emails using nodemailer. Email is hosted on hostinger.
Here is my configuration:

```
host: "smtp.hostinger.com",
port: 465,
secure: true,
auth: {
    user: process.env.GRIEVANCE_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.GRIEVANCE_EMAIL_PASSWORD,
},
```

But every time I encounter this error:
`Error occurred while sending the email: Invalid login: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:`

user and pass is correct as i log into hostinger webmail with the same credentials. I tried setting `secure: false`, adding `tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}` but nothing works. I have to deploy the project in 2 days, event ChatGPT can't help me.

Comment: have you checked the settings of the host? For example I had a similar problem using G-Mail. If you use a G-Mail account you have to allow 3rd party apps to login with the credentials in the account settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved using this configuration:

```
host: "smpt.hostinger.com",
secure: true, 
secureConnection: false,
tls: {
   ciphers: "SSLv3",
},
requireTLS: true,
port: 465,
debug: true,
connectionTimeout: 10000,
auth: {
    user: process.env.GRIEVANCE_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.GRIEVANCE_EMAIL_PASSWORD,
},
```

Comment: But now I encountered another problem. In localhost, it was working well but as I deployed the code on the server it showed "ERROR send Error: Connection timeout." **I want to die**. 

Comment: did you figure out the solution? I had the same problem. Not sending mails for gmail, yahoo. but sending perfectly to temp mails. Could you share me the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is only missing the correct host name. Hostinger uses titan rather than hosting webmails itself. Should look like the following:

```
host: "smtp.titan.email",
port: 465,
secure: true,
auth: {
    user: process.env.GRIEVANCE_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.GRIEVANCE_EMAIL_PASSWORD,
},
```